# Find the $n^{th}$ derivative of $y=\frac {x}{x^2+a^2}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Find the $n^{th}$ derivative of $y=\dfrac {x}{x^2+a^2}$.

My Attempt:
$$y=\dfrac {x}{x^2+a^2}$$
$$y=x.(x^2+a^2)^{-1}$$
Differentiating both sides with respect to $x$
$$y_{1}=x.((-1).(x^2+a^2)^{-2}.2x)+(x^2+a^2)^{-1}$$
$$y_{1}=(-1).(x^2+a^2)^{-2}.2x^2+(x^2+a^2)^{-1}$$

Comment: It's: $\frac{\partial ^n}{\partial x^n}\frac{x}{x^2+a^2}=\mathcal{L}_t\left[t^n \sin
   \left(\frac{n \pi }{2}+t x\right)\right](a)$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$y=\frac{x}{x^2+a^2}=\frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{1}{x-ia}+\frac{1}{x+ia} \right)$$
The nth derivative of $(x+b)^{-1}$ is given as
$$D^n (x+b)^{-1}=(-1)^n n!(x+b)^{-n-1}$$
Using this
$$D^n y= (-1)^n n!~ \Re (x+ia)^{-n-1}=(-1)^n n! (x^2+a^2)^{(-n-1)/2} \cos[(n+1) \tan^{-1}(a/x)].$$

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**:

Rewrite the definition of $y$ as $(x^2+a^2)y=x$, and apply Leibniz' formula for the $n$-th derivative of a product of functions: for $n>1$, we have
$$(x^2+a^2)y^{(n)}+2nx  y^{(n-1)}=0,$$
whence the recurrence relation
$$y^{(n)}=-\frac{2nx}{x^2+a^2}y^{(n-1)}.$$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** $\displaystyle\frac1x\left(\left(\frac xa\right)^2-\left(\frac xa\right)^4+\left(\frac xa\right)^6-\cdots\right)=\frac1x\times\frac{\left(\frac xa\right)^2}{1+\left(\frac xa\right)^2}=\frac x{x^2+a^2}$ and therefore$$\frac x{x^2+a^2}=\frac x{a^2}-\frac{x^3}{a^4}+\frac{x^5}{a^6}-\cdots.$$

Answer (score 0):

An alternative answer is as follows:
\begin{align*}
y^{(n)}&=\biggl(\frac{x}{x^2+a^2}\biggr)^{(n)}\\
&=\frac12\bigl[\ln\bigl(x^2+a^2\bigr)\bigr]^{(n+1)}\\
&=\frac12\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} \frac{(-1)^{k-1}(k-1)!}{(x^2+a^2)^{k}} B_{n+1,k}(2x,2,0,\dotsc,0)\\
&=\frac12\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} \frac{(-1)^{k-1}(k-1)!}{(x^2+a^2)^{k}} 2^{k} B_{n+1,k}(x,1,0,\dotsc,0)\\
&=\frac12\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} \frac{(-1)^{k-1}(k-1)!}{(x^2+a^2)^{k}} 2^{k} \frac{(n-k+1)!}{2^{n-k+1}} \binom{n+1}{k}\binom{k}{n-k+1}x^{2k-n-1}\\
&=\frac12\frac{(n+1)!}{(2x)^{n+1}}\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k!}\binom{k}{n-k+1}\frac{(2x)^{2k}}{(x^2+a^2)^{k}}.
\end{align*}

References

1. F. Qi and B.-N. Guo, *Explicit formulas for special values of the Bell polynomials of the second kind and for the Euler numbers and polynomials*, Mediterr. J. Math. **14** (2017), no. 3, Article 140, 14 pages; available online at https://doi.org/10.1007/s00009-017-0939-1.
2. F. Qi, D.-W. Niu, D. Lim, and Y.-H. Yao, *Special values of the Bell polynomials of the second kind for some sequences and functions*, J. Math. Anal. Appl. **491** (2020), no. 2, Article 124382, 31 pages; available online at https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jmaa.2020.124382.
3. Feng Qi, *Taylor's series expansions for real powers of two functions containing squares of inverse cosine function, closed-form formula for specific partial Bell polynomials, and series representations for real powers of Pi*, Demonstratio Mathematica **55** (2022), no. 1, 710--736; available online at https://doi.org/10.1515/dema-2022-0157.
4. Siqintuya Jin, Bai-Ni Guo, and Feng Qi, *Partial Bell polynomials, falling and rising factorials, Stirling numbers, and combinatorial identities*, Computer Modeling in Engineering & Sciences **132** (2022), no. 3, 781--799; available online at https://doi.org/10.32604/cmes.2022.019941.